# How to inject with IoC into Kotlin top level functions? Do I even use IoC containers?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, functional-programming, inversion-of-control, kotlin

I am having trouble to follow FP. When people say "more idiomatic style" I must understand that as : 99 % of Java libs are not applicable for FP idiomatic style for Kotlin and Scala right? Well, I need Spring Boot for quick startup with Vaadin. So I need to inject some beans.

```
package com.x.ui

import com.vaadin.icons.VaadinIcons
import com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator
import com.vaadin.ui.MenuBar

fun createMenuBar(navigator: Navigator): MenuBar {
    val menuBar = MenuBar()
    menuBar.setHeight(null)
    menuBar.setWidth(null)

    menuBar.addItem("Dashboard", VaadinIcons.COG,
            { navigator.navigateTo("Dashboard") } as MenuBar.Command)

    return menuBar
}
```

So how would I inject `SpringNavigator` in this case into this function?

As I have couple of top level functions so far, I have no @Component neither @Bean , what is idiomatic way to work with Spring IoC for Kotlin? Am I limited to using classes or we have tricks to do it?

Comment: Top-level functions are equivalent to Java static methods. I'm not sure whether it makes sense or would be a good practice injecting dependencies into them.

As a good practice, and IMHO, I would recommend you put these functions inside a class that you configure with dependency injection.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you have a function with the signature `(Navigator) -> MenuBar`, but what you probably want is a function with the signature `() -> MenuBar`.

Normally, in OO, you would accomplish this by injecting in the `Navigator` into the constructor, save the reference, and then use it when your function gets called.

In functional programming, the analogous concept is call "Partial Function Application". This is when you pre-apply parameters to a function and make a new function that takes the remaining parameters. In our case, we want to pre-apply the `Navigator` which will leave us with a signature of `() -> MenuBar`.

[This](https://realjenius.com/2017/08/24/kotlin-curry/) looks like a good article on the concept in Kotlin.

What I would suggest trying something like this:

```
// note - returns `() -> MenuBar` now, rather than `MenuBar`
fun createMenuBar(navigator: Navigator): () -> MenuBar {
    // returning a function that takes no parameters
    return { ->
        val menuBar = MenuBar()
        menuBar.setHeight(null)
        menuBar.setWidth(null)

        menuBar.addItem("Dashboard", VaadinIcons.COG,
            { navigator.navigateTo("Dashboard") } as MenuBar.Command)

        return menuBar
    }
}
```